# Calculating a percentage position of Z between X and Y

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so if i have 3 values:

```
x = 0;
y = 100;
z = 50;
```

The position of `z` between `x` and `y` is `50%`.

If `z` is `25`, the difference is `25%`.

How can I work this out with javascript? I want my return value to be like `0.5` or `0.25`

Thanks in advance from a first time StackOverflow user!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where your job is done for you. Though you could receive here some answers to your questions about the job you do. Consider therefore showing some job done (some actual code) by adding it to the question body.

Comment: Reminds me of http://r3dux.org/2010/06/add-a-number-to-another-number-in-javascript-solved/

Comment: @Felix, in all fairness, this is a tiny (very tiny) bit more complex, but +1 for making me laugh :-)

Comment: I'd say (z-x)/(y-x) is a fair bit more complex than x+y no?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple mathematical formula, just use the floating point calculation:

```
position = (z - x) / (y - x)
```

That will get you the relative position (0 through 1) of `z` within the range `x..y`, assuming `x <= z <= y` and `x < y`. If you want a percentage, simply multiply by 100.